# appending exports to a library

Tags: node.js, three.js

I am trying to append modules to the THREE.js library for example...

```
import * as THREE from 'three'// append the following routine to three when I import this file into app.js
export THREE.RenderPass = function (scene, camera, overrideMaterial, clearColor, clearAlpha) {
  THREE.Pass.call(this)

  this.scene = scene
  this.camera = camera

  this.overrideMaterial = overrideMaterial

  this.clearColor = clearColor
  this.clearAlpha = (clearAlpha !== undefined) ? clearAlpha : 0

  this.clear = true
  this.needsSwap = false
}

export THREE.RenderPass.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(THREE.Pass.prototype), {

  constructor: THREE.RenderPass,

  render: function (renderer, writeBuffer, readBuffer, delta, maskActive) {
    var oldAutoClear = renderer.autoClear
    renderer.autoClear = false

    this.scene.overrideMaterial = this.overrideMaterial

    var oldClearColor, oldClearAlpha

    if (this.clearColor) {
      oldClearColor = renderer.getClearColor().getHex()
      oldClearAlpha = renderer.getClearAlpha()

      renderer.setClearColor(this.clearColor, this.clearAlpha)
    }

    renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera, this.renderToScreen ? null : readBuffer, this.clear)

    if (this.clearColor) {
      renderer.setClearColor(oldClearColor, oldClearAlpha)
    }

    this.scene.overrideMaterial = null
    renderer.autoClear = oldAutoClear
  }

})
```

these routines have been ingrained into my solution which was previously raw java-script. I have moved it to webpack which bundles and parses it all requiring imports and exports. Previously I would just call these files after importing the library through a cdn and it would append to it. It appears its done differently in nodejs, and I'm unsure how to do it.

I need these modules to be accessible from the main library, they are used to enable post processing in three.js.

previously I did...

```
<!-- scripts appended based on the order I placed the script tags in the html, I bundle wiht webpack so this seems like a rather bad solution to continue when its already being 'bundled'-->
<script src="EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="MaskPass.js"></script>
<script src="ShaderPass.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you considered to use a pure ES6 workflow instead? All JS files in the examples directory are available as modules for a while now. So instead of importing them via `<script>` or extending the `THREE` namespace, you directly include the necessary files via `import` statements. More information about this topic in the following guide: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules (section `Importable Examples`).

Comment: @Mugen87 I solved the problem by painfully editing the code to work with imports, but my question still remains... How would I take a class and append it to a library using node and es6 syntax?